# ReadyAPI - How to store a 'run test case' step response?

Tags: soapui, ready-api

I a have several testSuites :

- one contains all the REST APIs I can use => api test suite
- one contains higher level testing that will use these APIs => use cases test suite

In my use cases, I call the api test suite requests using the 'run test case' step.

I find it not very convenient as I can't set any assertion on it and I have to do groovy scripting to get the distant (api test suite) testCase's response.

Is there a possibility, from my 'run test case', to store the distant testCase's response in a property for further use ?

thanks for any help

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the response as a test case property, then in your 'Run Test Case' options configuration, check that property as a return property.

Comment: Nice one, that will look cleaner than pure groovy scripting :)

Comment: @A.Joly if you're working with version control, I also highly recommend adding a teardown script that will clear out that property from the 'Run Test Case' step after each run. If you commit that file with some response and later run it again and sync, it will show as new changes if the responses don't match exactly.